# Vim colorscheme behaviour different when loading from vimrc / spf13

Tags: vim, color-scheme, spf13vim

I'm trying to load a default colorscheme `torte` by placing `colorscheme torte` on my `~/.vimrc.local` (I'm using [vIm SPF13](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim%20*Vim%20SPF13*) by the way if it means anything.)

Anyways, whenever I open vim, I end up seeing this. [image: Torte]

But when I execute `colorscheme torte` from the **command mode**, I get[image]

Anyone knows how to get the second image consistent? Thanks. :)

Comment: Drop spf13: it adds complexity where there is none while preventing you from learning vim and keeping control of *your* config.

Comment: I've been using vim for quite some time and just decided to use it so I'll see how other people use it too. :) But yeah, I removed spf13 and the color scheme is just like the second image.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `'background'` is changed at some point or another of the startup process which would explain the difference in looks. You can test it with:

```
:set background=light
:set background=dark
```

But the arbitrary and unneeded complexity introduced by your distribution makes it hard to guess where it's done or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're deliberately not adding color scheme to your .vimrc file.

If that is true, simply add this to your .vimrc file

```
if filereadable(glob("~/.vimrc.local")
    source ~/.vimrc.local
endif
```

Otherwise simply add it to your. vimrc file itself.